# Android Fatal Signal 11

Tags: java, android, crash, signals

In the app I'm developing on Android, I keep getting a Fatal Signal 11 error.

I think it's something to do with the way that I'm accessing the memory but I can't figure out what is causing it.

Here's the LogCat:

```
05-02 23:47:17.618: D/dalvikvm(590): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 4% free 6531K/6787K, paused 101ms
05-02 23:47:17.638: I/dalvikvm-heap(590): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.619MB for 1228816-byte allocation
05-02 23:47:17.738: D/dalvikvm(590): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 7730K/8007K, paused 5ms+14ms
05-02 23:47:17.878: D/dalvikvm(590): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 7730K/8007K, paused 37ms
05-02 23:47:17.888: I/dalvikvm-heap(590): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.790MB for 1228816-byte allocation
05-02 23:47:17.998: D/dalvikvm(590): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 8930K/9223K, paused 4ms+4ms
05-02 23:47:17.998: A/libc(590): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

Comment: Is part of your code written in C?

Comment: No, it's all written in Java.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had been trying to call an uninitialised Canvas inside another Class so when it was trying to get the height or width of it, it would crash.

Comment: Was there anything you did in particular to figure out your uninitiated `Canvas` was causing there error? I'm having the same problem, but I'm unsure where to find the root of it.

Comment: Isn't only about Canvas, I have experienced this error with a ´final Activity act´ which was passed used by an "AsyncTask in an AsyncTask" and this was also a problem for it.

Comment: I implemented Flurry and now it is giving this error `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x3f800010 (code=1), thread 28708 (com.application)` I have no idea what is going on. It is only giving this in one activity. Working fine in others. x.x

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with an instance of android.media.MediaRecorder.

The code accessed `#getMaxAmplitude()` after `#reset()` and `#release()` on the MediaRecorder instance had been called.

Comment: I had the same issue. how do you fix it?

Comment: There was no simple fix. I had to check where #getMaxAmplitude() was called after #reset() or #release().

Comment: maybe try nullifying your MediaRecorder object after you call #reset() or #relaese() and that should show you the relevant NPEs

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem this morning and was able to track it back to accidentally saving an image 800 pixels wide in the drawable-mdpi folder.  When I realized what happened I tinkered with it for a second.  I tried compressing it hard to see if it was related to file size and it was not.  Then I tried saving it again at 650 pixels wide and it worked out of that folder.  So somewhere between there is the breaking point for every folder I would guess.  Then I put the 800 p wide image in the intended hdpi folder and the 480 p wide in the mdpi and it fixed it.

Comment: It's wierd, but this seems to have fixed my problem as well, only my images were only 800*480.

Comment: I guess it goes by a set largest/smallest size in each folder.  Probably if the height or width exceeds it then it causes a hassle.  Glad it helped you, I know I was racking my brain on it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found after a good night of sleep and a coffee in the morning that I had been silly enough to back the canvas with an uninitialized Bitmap. It seems that much if not all of the canvas drawing code is native code and passing of uninitialized objects is not detected everywhere.

SIGSEGV with a null address (0x00000000) means that your application has dereferenced a null pointer, so look out for places where you pass null pointers (i.e. empty references to object instances you haven't instantiated in the first place) to code that is backed by native code and does not properly check for this error.

Comment: Checking nullpointers before starting a draw is a good idea thanks =)

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same Fatal error while using Canvas class.
My code looks likes this. The following piece of code initializes an Arc and draws it on the canvas.

```
private RectF r1 = null;
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public Arc(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    r1 = new RectF(200, 200, 400, 400);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   canvas.drawArc(r1, 0, 90, true, mPaint);
}
```

The problem occurred because my instance of RectF was not initialized which resulted in NullPointerException and the fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem when i was making a cocos2d-x app on android. the problem was that my layer was a CCLayer:

```
 CCLayer::init()
```

but in the header file i had:

```
 class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor
```

i changed CCLayerColor to CCLayer and my app worked

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me during game development using LibGDX framework for Android, and here's why:

I have 2 screens - `GameScreen` and `BattleScreen`. `GameScreen` is where I move my character on the map. When I have collision with enemy sprite I instantly use `game.setScreen(new BattleScreen(this))` and change current screen to `BattleScreen`. Here's where the Fatal Signal 11 used to happen. At first I thought it had something to do with loading assets, because my asset manager instance was static. I was trying multiple ways of loading them but nothing worked. It turned out I was changing the screen in the wrong place. For my `GameScreen` I had `WorldController` and `WorldRenderer` instance. I was using `worldController.update()` and `worldRenderer.render()` inside `GameScreen`'s `render(float deltaTime)` method. Inside `worldController.update()` I was checking for collisions and changing screen as soon as I found one with the enemy. It was not good for Android, maybe because it happened between update and render, or it took some time, while update was still running and it lead to conflicts - I don't know. But here is how I fixed it:

1. I added a boolean flag (false by default) inside `WorldController` and everytime a collision with enemy happened I was setting it to true
2. In `GameScreen`'s `render()` I was checking this flag - if it was true I would change the screen to `BattleScreen`, otherwise I would update and render `GameScreen`

Now it works perfectly everytime, no FATAL SIGNAL ERROR 11 whatsoever

Here's my `GameScreen`'s `render()` method:

```
@Override
public void render(float deltaTime) {

    if(worldController.isCollisionWithEnemy()) {

        game.setScreen(game.battleScreen);

    } else {

        if(!paused) {
            worldController.update(deltaTime);
        }

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(57.0f / 255.0f, 181.0f / 225.0f, 115.0f / 255.0f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        worldRenderer.render();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a null pointer exception inside an onDraw event that prevent the draw to be completed on the canvas. I think is a general error message given when a draw problem ocurr.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this error when using Libgdx for android, and I found out this error is
caused by Box2d which uses native code, it is better to look at part of your code which uses Box2d and see if there is any null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `BluetoothSocket` was null when trying to establish a Bluetooth connection