# How can i use the output in logcat after a Fatal Signal 11 to figure out where I am getting the error from in android native code?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, fatal-error

I have one bug to fix that pops up alot.  Its a Fatal Signal 11.  The problem is the program doesnt crash in any of my native code, but something else is causing it.  I have the following from logcat, I do not know the proper term for this:

```
03-10 12:50:14.419 F/libc    (3429): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778): Build fingerprint: 'hp/hp_tenderloin/tenderloin:4.0.4/IMM76I/330937:user/release-keys'
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778): pid: 3429, tid: 3702  >>> com.RefinedCode.handocr <<<
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  r0 004a1e30  r1 33400001  r2 004a1e30  r3 00000000
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  r4 414b3da8  r5 004b6cb8  r6 00000007  r7 4e348f80
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  r8 4e766c10  r9 4e348f78  10 00000008  fp 4e766c24
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  ip 2ac56f9c  sp 4e766c08  lr 2ac254dd  pc 2b10ba64  cpsr 60010010
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d4  4379000044310000  d5  437a0000442d8000
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d6  bff921fb54400000  d7  442a556b00000000
03-10 12:50:14.819 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d8  4392103d3089705f  d9  45a820003c711706
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d10 3f80000000000000  d11 3f800000000000ff
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d12 4017ef9a000000ff  d13 000000003f800000
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d14 3fee940d6bb98cc4  d15 3ff0000000000000
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000042ff0000
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d18 3fc5555555555549  d19 bf9b6d5dd2eaade7
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d20 3ef4e83ec07d9f84  d21 be5ae1fd202f348f
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d22 bc7a626331000000  d23 3de5d93a5acfd57c
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d24 ff00000000000000  d25 0000d8050000a9d8
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d26 0003e14a0018a8a0  d27 0002d8070002a9da
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d28 0000000000ff0000  d29 090a0b0c0d0e0f10
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  d30 0000000100000001  d31 0000000100000001
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778):  scr 60000010
03-10 12:50:14.829 I/DEBUG   (11778): 
03-10 12:50:14.999 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #00  pc 00088a64  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZNK6SkPath7isEmptyEv)
03-10 12:50:14.999 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #01  pc 0006e4da  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #02  pc 0001edb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #03  pc 00059050  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): code around pc:
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2b10ba44 e5903014 e3530000 03a00001 012fff1e  .0....S......./.
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2b10ba54 e3530001 13a00000 112fff1e e590300c  ..S......./..0..
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2b10ba64 e5d30000 e2700001 33a00000 e12fff1e  ......p....3../.
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2b10ba74 e1a03002 e5912008 e92d4010 e1530002  .0... ...@-...S.
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2b10ba84 e1a04000 3a000004 eddf7a09 edc07a01  .@.....:.z...z..
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): code around lr:
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2ac254bc ed78f7ca 463a4621 4605466e f7fc4668  ..x.!F:FnF.FhF..
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2ac254cc 4628faa3 bdf0b005 4610b510 ed70f7ca  ..(F.......F..p.
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2ac254dc bf00bd10 4610b510 f7ca4619 bd10ed70  .......F.F..p...
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2ac254ec 4610b510 ed70f7ca bf00bd10 4610b510  ...F..p........F
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 2ac254fc ed70f7ca bf00bd10 2030b570 f7c74615  ..p.....p.0 .F..
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): 
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778): stack:
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bc8  004b5270  [heap]
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bcc  004a1ac0  [heap]
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bd0  1d600005  
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bd4  2b2e62e3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bd8  004b2de0  [heap]
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bdc  004b6cb8  [heap]
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766be0  004b2de0  [heap]
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766be4  2ac1c5c1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766be8  41477d58  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bec  004b6cb8  [heap]
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bf0  00000004  
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bf4  4e348ee8  
03-10 12:50:15.019 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bf8  2b524910  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-10 12:50:15.019 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766bfc  2b524910  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-10 12:50:15.019 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766c00  df0027ad  
03-10 12:50:15.019 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766c04  00000000  
03-10 12:50:15.019 I/DEBUG   (11778): #01 4e766c08  414b3da8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
03-10 12:50:15.019 I/DEBUG   (11778):     4e766c0c  2b2b0db4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Usually when i get this kind of error, it is because of some of the native code I wrote messing up, like accessing an invalid element of a vector or something.

The problem usually happens sometimes after one of my native functions has run (but not in it), so its really hard for me to figure out how to fix it when I dont get a line number of where the problem is happening.  Is there a way I can use this output to get more information on the problem?  I dont know what the proper term for this output is so I am having a hard time searching for answers.  If anyone here has experience with this I would really like to be able to use this!

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: for starters you can add logs in your native code to pinpoint the error

Comment: Thats what I did, the error doesnt happen in my native code.

Comment: can u paste log of part above the point you get this error, also check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423128/android-fatal-signal-11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)` is `null pointer dereferencing`. As you can see address is `0x00000000`, so system is trying to read from address `0`.

```
03-10 12:50:14.999 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #00  pc 00088a64  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZNK6SkPath7isEmptyEv)
03-10 12:50:14.999 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #01  pc 0006e4da  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #02  pc 0001edb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
03-10 12:50:15.009 I/DEBUG   (11778):          #03  pc 00059050  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
```

Your crash is at `SkPath7isEmptyEv` - > `SkPath.isEmpty()`. (This is called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Complex_example))

So this is obviously a system / framework issue. I would try to create a minimal code to reproduce the issue to understand its nature and also search for known bug reports. Best would be to find a workaround not hitting this code path.

Comment: It's possible the problem is with the way the class is being used, and the crash can be corrected in the app sources.  `isEmpty()` isn't a virtual method, so it's possible the `this` pointer is null.  (That method really doesn't do much, so the set of things that can be going wrong is limited.)  If you want to assert that it's still a bug for the library to seg fault in this situation I won't argue. :-)

Comment: @fadden I don't know how deep in the function is PC but "r0 004a1e30  r1 33400001  r2 004a1e30  r3 00000000" it is r3 that's null. `this` should be on `r0` afaik however my c++ debugging skills is no where near an expert one.

Comment: Hmm.  Looking at the disassembly, I'd guess `this` is valid but `fPathRef` is `NULL`.  (First instruction loads *(R0+0) into R3, second instruction loads *(R3+16) into R0, next two compare R0 to zero and save it as a bool in R0.  It's crashing on the second one.)  Not sure what circumstances lead to this state.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Libskia seems to be a graphics library used by android, I believe my problem is being caused by not synchronizing access to a Path.  That name mangling really helped.  Also, Sorry for the late accept as correct answer!