# FATAL SIGNAL 11 on bitmap creation error

Tags: java, android, bitmap

in my code, i first do a call from native to create a bitmap in java (of size: 800 x 480). This call is made recursively by a callback function and the bitmap is created by created by this function:

```
public void createBitmap(byte[] buffer, int width, int height)  
{
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));  
}
```

Another native function then calls a java function that is required to select an area of the original bitmap and create a new bitmap. This is done by the function below. It selects the bitmap previously created by the above function and gets a part of it (x, y coordinates) then creates a new bitmap:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(int x, int y, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        AppLogger.LOGE("check : 1");
        AppLogger.LOGE("check : x" + bitmap.getWidth() + " Y : " + bitmap.getHeight());

        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x, y, 10, 1);

        AppLogger.LOGE("check : 2");

        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

        AppLogger.LOGE("check : 3");

        return bm;

    } else {
        AppLogger.LOGE("check : 4");
        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        return bm;
    }
}
```

I have however begun getting native out of space errors (at least that is what i think from the extensive search from similar problems). The error occurs on the first bitmap.create where i get part of the original image. Is there an issue with how i have done this? 
p.s - the bitmap creation is on a loop i.e it is done multiple times.
ERROR : Libc FATAL SIGNAL 11

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423128/android-fatal-signal-11  also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663671/creating-an-empty-bitmap-and-drawing-though-canvas-in-android

Comment: post the log. I suspect error at creating **resizedBitmap**

Comment: the error shown is fatal signal 11 (sigsegv) at some address (code=1)